# Including virtual attributes when responding_to a JSON call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a post model that has a virtual attribute that I would like to set and then include in a response to a JSON call to my post#index action.  I can't seem to get the virtual attribute to be included in the response.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :height
  attr_accessor :m_height
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def index
    story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    @posts = story.posts.where("posts.id >= ?", 100)
    @posts.each do |post|
      post.m_width = post.height * 200
    end
    results = { :total_views => story.total_views,  
                :new_posts => @posts }
    respond_with(results)
  end
end
```

I think that I must need something similar to `@post.to_json(:methods => %w(m_width))`, but I don't see how to use :methods in a respond_with

Comment: Oh man.  Sorry, I just woke up and didn't see the whole post or something.  Previous comments deleted because they're so irrelevant.  Looking into it for you more now, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>[This](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3) seems to provide the answer.  Implement a `to_json` and `to_xml` in your models, as appropriate, with definitions like:</strike>

There's a better answer implied [here](http://blog.gomiso.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Following code stolen from the post:

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge(:methods => [...], :only => [...], :include => [...])
  end
```

`to_json` won't be called on your model in this case, from what I can tell in the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1304298bd921976b8390a8d90bb533fd493e2867/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L58), but `as_json` will be, in the process of serialization.

So, here's what happens, in overview form:

1. You call `respond_with` with the results hash you've constructed.
2. Rails (ActionController) [calls to_json](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1304298bd921976b8390a8d90bb533fd493e2867/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb#L154) on that.
3. `to_json` [sends you over to](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1304298bd921976b8390a8d90bb533fd493e2867/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb#L16) [JSON::Encoding](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1304298bd921976b8390a8d90bb533fd493e2867/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L58) which keeps calling `as_json` all the way down until everything is JSONified.

That's why there was the confusion about `to_json` and `as_json` in an earlier version of this answer.

Comment: As soon as I saw this answer I realized that it was a good one . . . override the `to_json` call that is triggered by `respond_with`; how much more straight-forward can it be.  Unfortunately, and for reasons that I am not experienced enough to determine, my `to_json` method in the model isn't being triggered by the `respond_with` call in the controller.  If however, I add `@posts.first.to_json` to the above index action, that does trigger my custom to_json method.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Up to date.  That should give you a lot to chew on.  Let me know if it doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: Wow, you have gone above and beyond.  Thanks so much for the answer and additional cites.